# Automapper TMember doesn't get the expected value

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

**Models**

```
public class NodeInfo
{
    public double X { get; set; }
}

public class NetNode
{
    public double X { get; set; }
}
```

For the models above, I have the following map. Say the value of the "X" property of the source object is 5. I am expecting the value of "o" to be 5 but it is always 0. If I return "s.X" instead of "o" it works fine but I thought that the TMember should have returned the corresponding property value as well.

**Mapper Profile**

```
public class ProfileBase : Profile
{
    public ProfileBase()
    {
        CreateMap<NodeInfo, NetNode>()
        .ForMember(n => n.X, opt => opt.MapFrom((s, d, o, ctx) => o)).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I am using the following overloads for the mapping above.

```
IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember>

MapFrom<TResult>(Func<TSource, TDestination, TMember, ResolutionContext, TResult> mappingFunction);
```

**Execution**

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile(new ProfileBase());
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

NodeInfo nodeInfo = new() { X = 5 };
NetNode netNode;

netNode = mapper.Map<NetNode>(nodeInfo);
//netNode.X should be 5 but it is 0
//change the "=> o" in the profile to "=> s.X" and it returns 5
```

Comment: Try https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-converters.html. You'll have the source member there.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using ConvertUsing with the destination member provided as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `TMember` represents the destination member of the destination object, which is the `0` value of the `X` property of the the newly instantiated `NetNode` instance.

From the documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/73ba4003e49e37e5fffec49b67e7d9ea1cbb8a8a/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/IMemberConfigurationExpression.cs#L64):

> Map destination member using a custom function.
> Access the source, destination object, **destination member**, and
> context.

```
/// <summary>
/// Map destination member using a custom function. Access the source, destination object, destination member, and context.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Not used for LINQ projection (ProjectTo)</remarks>
/// <param name="mappingFunction">Function to map to destination member</param>
void MapFrom<TResult>(Func<TSource, TDestination, TMember, ResolutionContext, TResult> mappingFunction);
```

Comment: Thank you. I really don't understand why we don't have an overload for source members and destination members together. I needed to use them both in ForAllMembers which only has <TSource, TDestination, object>. So I had to reach to destination via opt.DestinationMember and then reach to source member using ConvertUsing by providing the destination member as parameter. I think this is pretty complicated.

Comment: In the general case there is _no_ source member. You do have a source member when you specify one, with a member value resolver or a value converter. A member value resolver has access to both the source and the destination member.

Comment: I see, in my specific case, I needed to convert the value of the source member to a specific format depending on the destination member's type property. So I was using PropertyInfo of destination member, Type of TSource and a custom field in the custom property descriptor for the converter method I am using for ConvertUsing.